# React Fetch with State Value

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, fetch

I've two different API URL. I can get current user's ID with /api/current_user and save into "**currentuser**" state. I want to fetch all **currentuser's** from MySQL. My API URL works. But i couldn't fetch with **currentuser** state variable.

This link returns **currentuser's** ID. It works.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/current_user/', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        setCurrentuser(json.id);
      });
  
  
},[])
```

Then i want to use that ID with **currentuser** state.

```
 Axios.request({
      method: 'POST',  
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/post',
      data: {
        curus: `${currentuser}`     // I'm trying to use currentuser state on here.
      },
     })

    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
  })
    .then(data => {
      let tmpArray2 = []
      const tmpArray = []
bla bla bla ...
```

Finally request payload returns **curus: ""**

So it have a null value. I can use this state value inside return function.

Also that's my node server's index.js:

```
app.post('/api/post', (req, res) => {
    const currentt = req.body.curus
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM messagestable WHERE sender='" + currentt + "' OR recipient ='" + currentt + "' ";
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
        res.send(result);
        console.log(currentt)
    });

})
```

I want to fetch all messages from MySQL but just for currentuser. Not all users messages. May you help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Give me more context: the first fecth to fill `currentuser` is done on component's loading. But when `Axios.request` fill be fired? On button's click? On component's loading? You wrote it on component's body?

Comment: Is the 'currentuser' state in the same context as the Axios Request ? For me, either the axios request is launched before the current user state has been defined OR the user state is null because not in the Axios Request component context. Also, your server is vulnerable to SQL injections, [check this link](https://blog.sqreen.com/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js-and-other-vulnerabilities/)

Comment: I'm using both of them inside a useEffect(). They come in succession. Top one is " fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/current_user/', {...." and second code block is bottom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `fetch` and `Axios.request` in succession because `setCurrentuser` is async and when you use `currentuser` in `Axios.request` you don't know if `currentuser` has the very last value.

Much better split `fetch` and `Axios.request` into 2 `useEffect` in this way:

```
useEffect(()=>{  //<-- this will be fired on component's loading
    
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/current_user/', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        setCurrentuser(json.id);
      });
  
  
},[]) 

useEffect(() => { //<-- this one will be fired every time you change currentuser and will contains the very last value of currentuser
  Axios.request({
  method: 'POST',  
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/post',
  data: {
    curus: `${currentuser}`
  },
 })

.then(response => {
  return response.data;
})
.then(data => {
  let tmpArray2 = []
  const tmpArray = []
  bla bla bla ...

}, [currentuser])
```

Comment: Oh that was so understandable. You are better then my all teachers! Thanks for everyone. Now i'm gonna look for SQL Injection issue. You are the best!

Comment: @HighPriv Thank you so much. Have a very nice coding =)